# 'git checkout' is not creating local branch to match remote tracking branch

Tags: git

On one machine, calling `git checkout` will not create a local branch.

For example, if I have a remote tracking branch `origin/master`, I can call `git checkout origin/master`, and it will work fine, putting me in a headless state.

But if I try to call `git checkout master`, I get the error `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

I tried this on another machine, and it worked just fine.

They have the exact same version of git installed (2.15.0.windows.1).  `git config --list` shows one difference.  The machine where it worked properly had the following line in its configuration:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

What would put that in the local configuration, why might it be missing from one of the systems, and what is the proper thing to do to fix the problem?

Comment: try `git fetch` before checkout

Comment: Running `git fetch` beforehand doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Answering the last part first:

> and what is the proper thing to do to fix the problem?

the simplest thing at this point is to run:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

so as to get this configuration line added.

#### Description

This:

> ```
> remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

is the normal, standard setting for `remote.origin.fetch`.

> What would put that in the local configuration,

Running:

```
git clone <url>
```

will do that, as step 4 of this six-step `clone` process:

1. Create new directory if/when appropriate.  (You can point it to an existing, empty directory instead, if you like.)
2. Run `git init` in the empty directory.
3. Run any specified `git config` operations in the new, empty repository.
4. Run `git remote add origin <url>`.
5. Run `git fetch origin`.
6. Run `git checkout <branch>`, where `<branch>` usually defaults to `master`.

> why might it be missing from one of the systems,

*Not* running `git clone`.  If you do the steps yourself, and do something odd instead of step 4, you will get this setup.  It's possible there is some kind of bug in some Windows version of Git since I have recently seen several questions where this has happened.

(Note: Running `git clone --single-branch -b <branch>` redirects the `git remote add` step to use `-t <branch>`, so that `remote.origin.fetch` will be set to something other than the standard setting.  The `git config` command at the top will overwrite the non-standard setting with the standard one.)

Comment: It's possible that something weird happened when it was originally cloned as part of a Jenkins job.

Comment: Jenkins might run `git clone --single-branch` along with a `-b` argument that limits or eliminates the setting (although I'd have to check the source code to see if there are cases that eliminate it entirely—normally `-b` sets up a `fetch` refspec that fetches the single branch or tag).

Comment: I think you kinda buried your lede there, the last three lines belong at the top.

Comment: @jthill: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Before checkout branch you should run fetch:

```
git fetch
git checkout master
```

Comment: Calling `git fetch` beforehand doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`git remote -v`

you should see the correct fetch and  push branches .
Else u can force and set it using below command

`git remote set-url origin <URL>`

Make sure URL is exacltly same url you used to clone the repo .

Answer (score 0):

To answer things sequentially to question,

Q: On one machine, calling `git checkout` will not create a local branch.

A: No it does not create branch, use `git checkout -b 'branch_name'` to create local branch

Q: But if I try to call git checkout master, I get the error error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

A: That's because you do not have remote references updated in your staging dir.

Run below in sequence

`git remote update` should sets things up to point to remote origin branches including master

`git fetch` -- Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their histories. Remote-tracking branches are updated (see the description of  below for ways to control this behavior). Ref : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

`git checkout master` -- Now will checkout master fetching from origin master & switches to it.

Earlier answer of running from `git clone <repo-url>` sets things up Or you can follow above to fix problem